# SwiftUI: append menu entry to group "View" after "Enter Full Screen"

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to append a new menu entry right below "Enter Full Screen", but I am failing to find the right `CommandGroupPlacement` property.

```swift
CommandGroup(after: .<what needs to be put here??>) {
   //my buttons here
}
```

Attempting to override "View" results in just another group with the same name (see image).

[image]

```swift
CommandMenu("View") {
     //add button here       
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shoutout to Majid Jabrayilov for his blogpost on this: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/11/24/commands-in-swiftui/

To find a solution to my above issue though I still had to think a bit around the corner–what does work is this:

```swift
CommandGroup(before: .toolbar) {
                Button("Foo") {
                    
                }
            }
```

This works, because the toolbar menu entry is located within "View" (even thought I don't have a toolbar in my app, the placement still works nonetheless...)

Answer (score 2):

You said you were looking for the proper `CommandGroupPlacement` so for your case (relative to full screen mode), you would technically want `CommandGroupPlacement.sidebar`.  `CommandGroupPlacement.toolbar` works because toolbar options live in the `View` menu, though you have none set.

```
/// Example in a CommandsBuilder
CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.sidebar) {
    Button("New View Action", action: { print("After sidebar menu options") }).keyboardShortcut("s", modifiers: [.command, .option, .control, .function]
}
```

This should also come in handy for others.  The Apple documentation that corresponds to this: [CommandGroupPlacement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/commandgroupplacement)